# Hibernate lazy initialization requirement

Tags: hibernate, jpa

if we annotated a property as lazy initialization true, we cannot access the property. Eg

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="orgTypeID")
    private OrganizationType type;
```

we cannot access the organization type. then what is the need of declaring such field and getter and setters on the class?

we don't need to join. appreciate if you can explain this.

Comment: Why can't you access it using the getter? Are you getting some kind of error? What do you mean by _we don't need to join_? Do you only need to map the `OrganizationType` id ?

Comment: if we try to access it that object is null. but actually data is there.

Comment: when i debug for the organization type value is as 'org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer'

Comment: Lazy means it isn't immediately fetched, but will be fetched from the database/cache when it is first accessed.  Some providers are able to fetch it from the database outside of the current context, but not all.  So if you close the entityManager you used to read the entity, your lazy reference may no longer work, and if you serialize the entity, it definetely won't work unless you already caused it to be fetched.  There many tutorials and documentation explaining this if you look around.  Explain more of what you want and the problem you are hitting if this isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Objects with 'lazy' fetch will not be fetched unless they are asked for.

For the fetching to happen lazily, the object has to be still in a session context. If you try to access this lazy property outside of the session context(a detached object), you will see a lazyinitialization error on the server - no session issue.

To put the object back into the session, you have to open a session and merge the object into the session and try to fetch the lazy property.

To solve your issues, if you anticipate that this lazy property will be fetched in the future, you have to manually fetch it when the parent is loaded in the following fashion.

```
Session session = factory.getSession();

Class clas = session.find(Class.class, id);

clas.type();//here you are anticipating that it will be used somewhere else, so force it to load

session.close();
//    clas.type(); // Hypothetically, if you try to load the type here, this may not work as the session is closed before this line. the object is now in detached state.
```

Hope it answers your question.